# When does program recognize EOF?

Tags: c, file, stream

I made a simple C code for comparing two occasions of file stream. Both are reading .txt file and writing what it read to new .dat file(binary). The question is that the result file is different depending on the location of cursor in .txt file, which means whether '\n' exists at the end of file. Left case doesn't have '\n' at the last sentence, but right case does. I think this is related with "when does program notice 'EOF'?". Please help me.
[image]

and code is below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    FILE* src = fopen("/Users/Chois/Desktop/test.txt", "rt");
    FILE* dest = fopen("/Users/Chois/Desktop/dest.dat", "wb");

    char buff[50];
    int countOfWirte = 0;

    if(src!=NULL && dest!=NULL){
        fgets(buff, 50, src);
        while(!feof(src)){
            fwrite(buff, sizeof(char), 50, dest);
            countOfWirte++;
            fgets(buff, 50, src);
         }
    }else{
        printf("fail");
    }

    printf("fwrite work %d times\n", countOfWirte);

    fclose(src);
    fclose(dest);
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the while condition to

```
while (fgets(buff, 50, src) != NULL)
```

when `fgets()` tries to read beyond the `EOF` then the indicator is set, so `feof()` would return true after the failed read, if you instead check for the return value of `fgets()` which will return `NULL` at the end of file, you would avoid this problem.

This question is asked with some frequency and there is a good answer to it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26557243/1983495)

Also, you should not do this

```
fwrite(buff, sizeof(char), 50, dest);
```

because you don't know whether `50` `char`s where successfully read, instead use `fread()` like

```
size_t readBytes; 

while ((readBytes = fread(buf, 1, sizeof(buf), src)) > 0)
{
    fwrite(buf, 1, readBytes, dest);
    countOfWrite++;
}
```

Or if you want to read lines from the file, then `fprintf()` would be aproppriate

```
while (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), src) != NULL)
{
    fprintf(dest, "%s", buf);
    countOfWrite++;
}
```

Oh, and `sizeof(char)` must be `1`.